# php covert a Hexadecimal number 273ef9 into a path 27/3e/f9

Tags: php, algorithm

As the title reads, what it is an effeicent way to covert a Hexadecimal number such as `273ef9` into a path such as `27/3e/f9` in PHP?

**updated:::**
actually, I want a unsual number convert to dexadecimal and furthr convert to a path....but may be we can skip the middle step.

Comment: Are there always 6 hex digits?

Comment: converting to hex is quite unrelated, but try http://php.net/manual/en/function.dechex.php

Comment: @Michael,,,I am using that function to convert a number to hex

Comment: No need to skip the middle step, as by definition you want to convert to hex then to path. If you want to skip it, you'll need to write your own decimal to hex converter and the one that is built in is much more efficient (internally written in C instead of PHP). So don't worry about it and just use the str_split and implode to get the job done after dechex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about combining a str_split with implode? Might not be super efficient but very readable:

`implode('/',str_split("273ef9",2));`

As a side note, this will of course work well with larger hex strings and can handle partial (3,5,7 in length) hex numbers (by just printing it as a single letter after the last slash).

Edit: With what you're asking now (decimal -> hex -> path), it would look like this:

```
$num = 2572025;
$hex = dechex($num);
implode('/',str_split($hex,2));
```

Of course, you can combine it for an even shorter but less readable representation:
`implode('/',str_split(dechex($num),2));`

Comment: looks nice,,if there is no better one before I can accept. I will accept this.

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient approach is to touch each character in the hex value exactly once, building up the string as you go.  Because the string may have either an odd or even number of digits, you'll have to start with a check for this, outputting a single digit if it's an odd-length string.  Then use a for loop to append groups of two digits, being careful with whether or not to add a slash.  It will be a few lines of code.

Unless this code is being executed many millions of times, it *probably* isn't worth writing out this algorithm; Michael Petrov's is so readable and so nice.  Go with this unless you have a real need to optimize.

By the way, to go from a decimal number to a hex string, just use `dechex` :)

Comment: Exactly, I like how elegantly this is stated - it will take thousands to millions of executions of the code to make a difference. You could write something really efficient to convert the decimal directly into the path, but I doubt that even then it will be great - usually I choose readability over extreme efficiency until I can profile and identify the real bottlenecks in my code.